# axios.get() returns document html, but if i use axios.post() returns the data i want

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Fakultas.Vue

```
loadFakultas(){
  axios.get('fakultas')
    .then(({data}) => (this.fakultas = data.data));
}
```

FakultasController

```
public function index(){
  return ['message' => 'sukses']
}
```

Route

```
Route::resources([
  'admin' => 'AdminController',
  'fakultas' => 'FakultasController'
]);
```

In this case, if I use `axios.post('getFakultas')` and dan route

```
Route::post('getFakultas','fakultasController@getFakultas');
```

I can get the data what I want

Comment: can you run `php artisan route:list` in your terminal and paste the result?

Comment: I think you need to name your controller methods certain things since you are using a resource route. I think you need to rename your `getFakultas` method to `show`. Check out the "Actions Handled By Resource Controller" in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers